# Nuxt hook not fired

Tags: nuxtjs3, nuxt3

In a simple Nuxt 3 application with a hook on ready, the hook is not fired.

I have a plugin with:

```js
export default defineNuxtPlugin(async nuxtApp => {

  let commitBlockHeight;
  nuxtApp.hook('ready', async () => {
    console.log('Fetch block height')
    const [{ height }] = await $fetch('https://mempool.space/api/v1/blocks');
    commitBlockHeight = height;
  });

  return {
    provide: {
      commitBlockHeight
    }
  }
});
```

And a page with:

```js
<script setup>
  const { $commitBlockHeight } = useNuxtApp();
</script>

<template>
  <div>{{ $commitBlockHeight }}</div>
</template>
```

However, the variable is undefined and also the console log isn't logged.
Simply, the hook is not fired.
What could be the issue?

I have a reproduction [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-sglj8y?file=app.vue,plugins%2Ftest.js), but here obviously doesn't work since I can't run nuxt build and nuxt start.

My final goal is to fetch the mempool api just once, after nuxt build and nuxt start are competed, and then always display the same result every time someone visits the page.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, the 'ready' hook is only for hooks inside the `nuxt.config.ts`

E.g.

```js
// https://v3.nuxtjs.org/api/configuration/nuxt.config
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    hooks: {
        'ready': () => {
            console.log('Ready')
        }
    }
})
```

As far as I know using the `ready` hook inside the plugin will throw an error.

In your case, if you want to fetch and provide data when it is app is ready then this implementation will work for you.

`~/plugins/mempool.ts`

```js
export default defineNuxtPlugin(async () => {
    const { data } = await useFetch('https://mempool.space/api/v1/blocks')
    return {
        provide: {
            commitBlockHeight: data.value
        }
    }
})
```

In the component

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
onMounted(() => {
  console.log('App is ready')
  const { $commitBlockHeight } = useNuxtApp()
  console.log($commitBlockHeight)
})
</script>
<template>
  <div>

  </div>
</template>
```

Expected output
[image]

Comment: I tried also your solution before posting the question, But with that code, mempool api is fetched every time the user visits the page. What I want is to fetch it just once, after `nuxt build` and `nuxt start` are competed, and then always display the same result every time someone visits the page. I edited the question to make it more clear.